# How to get URL of Facebook Post made using Graph API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I have been able to successfully post a status update with image to Facebook using the graph API via an AJAX call. Now I would like to get the URL of the post, and redirect the user to the post as soon as it has been made, but I can't figure out how to get the URL. I thought the URL would be included in the response success data object, but I have tried iterating through it, and all I got was seemingly random numbers. Does anyone know how I can get the URL of the post and send the user there? Thanks. Here is my code below:

```
 $.ajax({
                url:"https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/photos?access_token=" + accessToken,
                type:"POST",
                data:fd,
                processData:false,
                contentType:false,
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("success " + data);
                    for (var key in data) {
                     if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                         var obj = data[key];
                          for (var prop in obj) {
                            // important check that this is objects own property 
                            // not from prototype prop inherited
                            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                              console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
                            }
                         }
                      }
                    }
                },
                error:function(shr,status,data){
                    console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
                },
                complete:function(){
                    console.log("Ajax Complete");
                }
            });
```

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/{post_id}` should work, it will automatically redirect the user to the correct full address.

Comment: According to the [API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating) you should get back an object with id, and post_id keys, so just add data.post_id to facebook url